# Trying to figure out how to run J2SE application on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04

My application is written in Java (J2SE) and was originally designed for a Windows environment. It was written on a Windows OS. I am now trying to figure out how to get the application to run on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and have no idea where to start. I have multiple supporting libraries (`.jar` files) that I have no idea how to package together for linux. Much less how to create any type of executable. I know that an .exe file will not work and I cannot use WINE.

I also have the issue of different file paths. I have some hardcoded paths (`C:\folder\xxx.txt`) and need to change them so the application can write and read to them on either OS. Not sure how to proceed with this one either other than testing for a specific OS and changing the paths accordingly.

Making this all more complicated is the fact that my Linux experience is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get some familiarity with how applications are used on Linux.  It will make the process easier, and will help you do a good job.

Secondly, remove any hardcoded paths of any kind from your source code.  All paths should be specified by the user, or at very least stored in a `.properties` file and read in at run time.  This is good practice even if you are only targeting one OS: why do you expect that your users are OK with you putting a new folder in their C: drive on Windows?

As for where your files go, the easiest way to deal with this is to create a single tarball (tar.gz archive) containing all your JARs and other resources, and a single Bourne shell script called by the name of your program (with no extension).  The script can find the JARs and launch the `java` executable (which is usually under `/usr/bin/java`) to start your application.

You'll probably get more help if you ask specific questions about specific steps of the problem.  If you're just looking for things like where the appropriate folders are located, then the correct place is probably [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/); if you need user-level help, then [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) is probably the right place.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The .properties file is a great idea. I am implementing it now and checking the OS in use and using a different .properties file for each OS. The program is made to work with our micro-controller and any user installing it is typically a technician who does not care where it is installed.

Comment: Now I just have to read up on tarballs and Bourne shell scripts(like a batch file?). Next is figuring out how and where to install the JRE files I use and trying to learn how to create an install for all this stuff. I will check out the links you provided and see if I can get any answers to these questions there. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @Ray: Glad I could help.  If you found this answer useful, you can always vote it up and/or [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Not sure if you still get updates of this Dan but I have a followup question. I have created a .tar.gz file with myProgram.jar in it as well as 5 supporting library .jar files. Where do I put this? Do I need to extract it on the Linux machine? Does the shell script go inside the tar.gz? I have read that if you write the shell script on a windows machine you can have issues once you move it to the Linux machine, so I am writing the shell script on the Linux machine using gedit. If I need to include it in my tar.gz file can I just move it to a memory stick? I am just unsure of the next step.

Comment: @Ray: Can you ask this as a new question?  (Click the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page.)  That way other people besides me can answer it.